# Update Recylerview : notifyDataSetChanged() doesn't work with a ArrayList from SharedPreference

Tags: android, arraylist, android-recyclerview, sharedpreferences, android-adapter

I have two buttons **(Add contact)** and **(Clear All Contacts)**, each time I fill information about the contact (name, phone, picture) I save them using `SharedPreference`, so if I close the app and reopen it again, items should appear, but in my code below, whenever I try to add or remove contact nothing happening I should close the app and open it again to make `RecylerView` updated.

**MainActivity**

```
        contactAdapter = new ContactAdapter(getApplicationContext(), getExistedContactList(), new onRecyclerViewClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view, Contact contact) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, contact.getFullName(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
        recyclerView.setAdapter(contactAdapter);
```

**Add Contact**

```
add.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Contact contact = new Contact();
                contact.setFullName(fullName.getText().toString());
                contact.setPhoneNumber(phoneNumber.getText().toString());
                contact.setContactProfilePictureURI(contactPictureUri.toString());
                contacts.add(contact);
                addToDB(fullName.getText().toString(), phoneNumber.getText().toString(), contactPictureUri.toString()); /*Add to database*/
                recyclerView.setAdapter(contactAdapter);
                contactAdapter.updateContactList(); /* Refresh/Update UI */
                addContactDialog.dismiss(); /* dismiss Contact Dialog */
            }
        });
```

**Remove all contact**

```
    private void removeAllContact() {
        contacts.clear();
        tinydb.clear();
        contactAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();/* Update UI */
    }
```

**Saving data using** `SharedPreference`

```
 void addToDB(String fullName, String number, String uri) {
        tinydb = new TinyDB(getApplicationContext());
        ArrayList<Contact> postObjects = tinydb.getListObject("CONTACT_KEY", Contact.class);
        ArrayList<Contact> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
        for (Object objs : postObjects) {
            arrayList.add((Contact) objs);
        }
        Contact mContact = new Contact();
        mContact.setFullName(fullName);
        mContact.setPhoneNumber(number);
        mContact.setContactProfilePictureURI(uri);
        arrayList.add(mContact);
        tinydb.putListObject("CONTACT_KEY", arrayList);
    }

 private List<Contact> getExistedContactList() {
        tinydb = new TinyDB(getApplicationContext());
        ArrayList<Contact> arrayList;
        arrayList = tinydb.getListObject("CONTACT_KEY", Contact.class);
        if (arrayList.size() == 0)
            return contacts;
        else
            return arrayList;
    }
```

Comment: I'm not sure your adapter is created again each time you call it. You should add an `update()` method in your adapter to update the current list instead of creating a new one each time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define Contact list on top of the class:

```
ArrayList<Contact> contactList = new ArrayList<>();
```

Now send it to the adapter and set the adapter to `Recyclerview` in `onCreate` only once.

```
contactList.clear();
contactList.addAll(getExistedContactList());
    contactAdapter = new ContactAdapter(getApplicationContext(), contactList, new onRecyclerViewClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view, Contact contact) {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, contact.getFullName(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
        });
        recyclerView.setAdapter(contactAdapter);
```

Now on click of Add button:

```
add.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Contact contact = new Contact();
                contact.setFullName(fullName.getText().toString());
                contact.setPhoneNumber(phoneNumber.getText().toString());
                contact.setContactProfilePictureURI(contactPictureUri.toString());
                contactList.add(contact);
                addToDB(fullName.getText().toString(), phoneNumber.getText().toString(), contactPictureUri.toString()); /*Add to database*/
                contactAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                addContactDialog.dismiss(); /* dismiss Contact Dialog */
            }
        });
```

Similary write code for cleaning the contact list from Db and update UI.